# how to upload a multi page reactjs app on godaddy cpanel

Tags: reactjs, react-router, hosting, cpanel

I have a multi-page app in reactjs that I am trying to host on GoDaddy. After running npm build, I upload the files to GoDaddy as per their instructions and I am able to view my login page i.e my homepage without any trouble. When I try to navigate to another page such as the dashboard page, the URL is changing but the page doesn't show any content on it I don't get any error in console either please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router';

// Then in render
<HashRouter history={ hashHistory }>
  ...
</HashRouter>
```

Comment: where to change this i am new to react js please help.

Comment: Where you have your BrowserRouter component

Comment: i don't have any browser router i have some other syntax i have something like this const routes = [
  { path: }`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`, exact: true, name: 'Home' },  as routes